# Incremental entropy computation

Tags: c++, algorithm, decision-tree, entropy

Let `std::vector<int> counts` be a vector of positive integers and let `N:=counts[0]+...+counts[counts.length()-1]` be the the sum of vector components. Setting `pi:=counts[i]/N`, I compute the entropy using the classic formula `H=p0*log2(p0)+...+pn*log2(pn)`.

The `counts` vector is changing --- counts are incremented --- and every 200 changes I recompute the entropy. After a quick google and stackoverflow search I couldn't find any method for incremental entropy computation. So the question: Is there an incremental method, [like the ones for variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm), for entropy computation?

EDIT: Motivation for this question was usage of such formulas for incremental information gain estimation in [VFDT](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/kdd00.pdf)-like learners.

**Resolved:** See [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133977/incremental-entropy-computation/134376#134376).

Comment: You might want to try heading over to [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions) to get a more detailed mathematical treatment of your question.

Comment: Shaktal, I posted the question on the mathoverflow, where they pointed out the following paper: http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/60/90/65/PDF/RR-7663.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I derived update formulas and algorithms for entropy and Gini index and made the note [available on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6348). (The working version of the note is available [here](http://blazsovdat.com/publications/incremental.pdf).) Also see [this mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133977/incremental-entropy-computation/134376#134376) answer.

For the sake of convenience I am including simple Python code, demonstrating the derived formulas:

```py
from math import log
from random import randint
      
# maps x to -x*log2(x) for x>0, and to 0 otherwise 
h = lambda p: -p*log(p, 2) if p > 0 else 0

# update entropy if new example x comes in 
def update(H, S, x):
  new_S = S+x
  return 1.0*H*S/new_S+h(1.0*x/new_S)+h(1.0*S/new_S)

# entropy of union of two samples with entropies H1 and H2
def update(H1, S1, H2, S2):
  S = S1+S2
  return 1.0*H1*S1/S+h(1.0*S1/S)+1.0*H2*S2/S+h(1.0*S2/S)

# compute entropy(L) using only `update' function 
def test(L):
  S = 0.0 # sum of the sample elements
  H = 0.0 # sample entropy 
  for x in L:
    H = update(H, S, x)
    S = S+x
  return H

# compute entropy using the classic equation 
def entropy(L):
  n = 1.0*sum(L)
  return sum([h(x/n) for x in L])

# entry point 
if __name__ == "__main__":
  L = [randint(1,100) for k in range(100)]
  M = [randint(100,1000) for k in range(100)]
  
  L_ent = entropy(L)
  L_sum = sum(L)
  
  M_ent = entropy(M)
  M_sum = sum(M)
  
  T = L+M
  
  print("Full = ", entropy(T))
  print("Update = ", update(L_ent, L_sum, M_ent, M_sum))
```

---

Answer (score -1):

You could re-compute the entropy by re-computing the counts and using some simple mathematical identity to simplify the entropy formula

```
K = count.size();
N = count[0] + ... + count[K - 1];
H = count[0]/N * log2(count[0]/N) + ... + count[K - 1]/N * log2(count[K - 1]/N)
  = F * h
h = (count[0] * log2(count[0]) + ... + count[K - 1] * log2(count[K - 1]))
F = -1/(N * log2(N))
```

which holds because of `log2(a / b)` == `log2(a) - log2(b)`

Now given an old vector `count` of observations so far and another vector of new 200 observations called `batch`, you can do in C++11

```
void update_H(double& H, std::vector<int>& count, int& N, std::vector<int> const& batch)
{
    N += batch.size();
    auto F = -1/(N * log2(N));
    for (auto b: batch)
       ++count[b];
    H = F * std::accumulate(count.begin(), count.end(), 0.0, [](int elem) { 
        return elem * log2(elem);
    });
}
```

Here I assume that you have encoded your observations as `int`. If you have some kind of symbol, you would need a symbol table `std::map<Symbol, int>`, and do a lookup for each symbol in `batch` before you update the `count`.

This seems the quickest way of writing some code for a general update. If you know that in every batch only few counts actually change,  you can do as @migdal does and keep track of the changing counts, subtract their old contribution to the entropy and add the new contribution.