# Calculating Incremental Entropy for Data that is not real numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, python-3.5, entropy

I have a set of data for which has an ID, timestamp, and identifiers. I have to go through it, calculate the entropy and save some other links for the data. At each step more identifiers are added to the identifiers dictionary and I have to re-compute the entropy and append it. I have really large amount of data and the program gets stuck due to growing number of identifiers and their entropy calculation after each step. I read the following solution but it is about the data consisting of numbers.
[Incremental entropy computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104673/incremental-entropy-computation)

I have copied two functions from this page and the incremental calculation of entropy gives different values than the classical full entropy calculation at every step.
Here is the code I have:

```
from math import log
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Functions copied from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104673/incremental-entropy-computation
# maps x to -x*log2(x) for x>0, and to 0 otherwise
h = lambda p: -p*log(p, 2) if p > 0 else 0

# entropy of union of two samples with entropies H1 and H2
def update(H1, S1, H2, S2):
    S = S1+S2
    return 1.0*H1*S1/S+h(1.0*S1/S)+1.0*H2*S2/S+h(1.0*S2/S)

# compute entropy using the classic equation
def entropy(L):
    n = 1.0*sum(L)
    return sum([h(x/n) for x in L])
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Below is the input data (Actually I read it from a csv file)
input_data = [["1","2008-01-06T02:13:38Z","foo,bar"], ["2","2008-01-06T02:12:13Z","bar,blup"], ["3","2008-01-06T02:13:55Z","foo,bar"],
          ["4","2008-01-06T02:12:28Z","foo,xy"], ["5","2008-01-06T02:12:44Z","foo,bar"], ["6","2008-01-06T02:13:00Z","foo,bar"],
          ["7","2008-01-06T02:13:00Z","x,y"]]
total_identifiers = {} # To store the occurrences of identifiers. Values shows the number of occurrences
all_entropies = []  # Classical way of calculating entropy at every step
updated_entropies = []  # Incremental way of calculating entropy at every step
for item in input_data:
    temp = item[2].split(",")
    identifiers_sum = sum(total_identifiers.values())  # Sum of all identifiers
    old_entropy = 0 if all_entropies[-1:] == [] else all_entropies[-1]  # Get previous entropy calculation
    for identifier in temp:
        S_new = len(temp)  # sum of new samples
        temp_dictionaty = {a:1 for a in temp}  # Store current identifiers and their occurrence
        if identifier not in total_identifiers:
            total_identifiers[identifier] = 1
        else:
            total_identifiers[identifier] += 1
    current_entropy = entropy(total_identifiers.values())  # Entropy for current set of identifiers
    updated_entropy = update(old_entropy, identifiers_sum, current_entropy, S_new)
    updated_entropies.append(updated_entropy)

    entropy_value = entropy(total_identifiers.values())  # Classical entropy calculation for comparison. This step becomes too expensive with big data
    all_entropies.append(entropy_value)

print(total_identifiers)
print('Sum of Total Identifiers: ', identifiers_sum)  # Gives 12 while the sum is 14 ???
print("All Classical Entropies:     ", all_entropies)  # print for comparison
print("All Updated Entropies:       ", updated_entropies)
```

The other issue is that when I print "Sum of total_identifiers", it gives **12** instead of **14**! (Due to very large amount of data, I read the actual file line by line and write the results directly to the disk and do not store it in the memory apart from the dictionary of identifiers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @blazs for providing the entropy_holder class. That solves the problem. So the idea is to import entropy_holder.py from (https://gist.github.com/blazs/4fc78807a96976cc455f49fc0fb28738) and use it to store the previous entropy and update at every step when new identifiers come.

So the minimum working code would look like this:

```
import entropy_holder

input_data = [["1","2008-01-06T02:13:38Z","foo,bar"], ["2","2008-01-06T02:12:13Z","bar,blup"], ["3","2008-01-06T02:13:55Z","foo,bar"],
          ["4","2008-01-06T02:12:28Z","foo,xy"], ["5","2008-01-06T02:12:44Z","foo,bar"], ["6","2008-01-06T02:13:00Z","foo,bar"],
          ["7","2008-01-06T02:13:00Z","x,y"]]

entropy = entropy_holder.EntropyHolder() # This class will hold the current entropy and counts of identifiers
for item in input_data:
    for identifier in item[2].split(","):
        entropy.update([entropy_holder.CountChange(identifier, 1)])

print(entropy.entropy())
```

This entropy by using the Blaz's incremental formulas is very close to the entropy calculated the classical way and saves from iterating over all the data again and again.

Answer (score 1):

The code above uses Theorem 4; it seems to me that you want to use Theorem 5 instead (from the paper in the next paragraph).

Note, however, that if the number of identifiers is really the problem then the incremental approach below isn't going to work either---at some point the dictionaries are going to get too large.

Below you can find a proof-of-concept Python implementation that follows the description from [Updating Formulas and Algorithms for Computing Entropy and Gini Index from Time-Changing Data Streams](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6348).

```
import collections
import math
import random


def log2(p):
    return math.log(p, 2) if p > 0 else 0


CountChange = collections.namedtuple('CountChange', ('label', 'change'))


class EntropyHolder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counts_ = collections.defaultdict(int)

        self.entropy_ = 0
        self.sum_ = 0

    def update(self, count_changes):
        r = sum([change for _, change in count_changes])

        residual = self._compute_residual(count_changes)

        self.entropy_ = self.sum_ * (self.entropy_ - log2(self.sum_ / (self.sum_ + r))) / (self.sum_ + r) - residual

        self._update_counts(count_changes)

        return self.entropy_

    def _compute_residual(self, count_changes):
        r = sum([change for _, change in count_changes])
        residual = 0

        for label, change in count_changes:
            p_new = (self.counts_[label] + change) / (self.sum_ + r)
            p_old = self.counts_[label] / (self.sum_ + r)

            residual += p_new * log2(p_new) - p_old * log2(p_old)

        return residual

    def _update_counts(self, count_changes):
        for label, change in count_changes:
            self.sum_ += change
            self.counts_[label] += change

    def entropy(self):
        return self.entropy_



def naive_entropy(counts):
    s = sum(counts)
    return sum([-(r/s) * log2(r/s) for r in counts])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(naive_entropy([1, 1]))
    print(naive_entropy([1, 1, 1, 1]))

    entropy = EntropyHolder()
    freq = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for _ in range(100):
        index = random.randint(0, 5)
        entropy.update([CountChange(index, 1)])
        freq[index] += 1

    print(naive_entropy(freq.values()))
    print(entropy.entropy())
```